# HtmlAgilityPack - Leave markup exactly as inputted

Tags: asp.net, string, html-agility-pack

Is there a way to set HtmlAgilityPack to leave the markup exactly as it was inputted? My issue is that I allow users to set the html layout of a data output on their website. The format they use is similar to ASP.NET's repeater control.

Take the following example:

```
<table>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
               <td>
                    <div>Item Markup</div>
               </td>          
     </ItemTemplate>
     <AltItemTemplate>
               <td>
                    <div>Alternate Item Markup</div>
               </td>
           </tr>
     </AltItemTemplate>
</table>
```

When I load this into HtmlAgilityPack, it will add the closing `tr` tag to the `ItemTemplate` and remove the actual closing `tr` tag from the `AltItemTemplate`. Later in the processing, the `<ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>` and the alternate tags are removed, which would result in valid html. When HtmlAgilityPack loads this in, it will not result in valid html.

I can and have successfully parsed this via string manipulation, however, I thought if I could use HtmlAgilityPack then it would be more efficient and easier to work with.

Anyone know if I can use HtmlAgilityPack to do this? or if I should just stick with the string manipulation (.NET's substring, indexof, remove, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. If you need to manipulate the content as a DOM, the HTML has to be correctly nested.

However, if you can live with all TR content as pure text (not DOM), than you could add this at the beginning of your processing:

```
ElementsFlags.Add("tr", HtmlElementFlag.CanOverlap | HtmlElementFlag.Empty);
```

But like if say, if you do this, everything between TR tags will be seen as text data, not as a DOM tree, so for example, you won't be able to do XPATH queries on the child DIV nodes.

Comment: I would need to access the child elements. I decided to just stick with my manual parsing using .NET's built-in string methods. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Well to tell HTMLAgilityPack to not try to fix the tags closers, you need to remove the tag from the elements flags:

```
dim hp as HtmlDocument
hp.LoadHTML(htmlcode)
hp.DocumentNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("tr")
```

Now check the hp.DocumentNode and you will see that HTMLAgilityPack didnt attempt to fix the tags closers

```
Dim dnode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = hp.DocumentNode
dim tosee as strin = dnode.OuterHTML
```